# For what reasons would a site be excluded from a full crawl?

Tags: search, crawling, site

This is what I've checked so far:

- The default page of the site is published
- In site admin it is set to 'allow this site to appear in search results'
- In site admin of the root site, it will search all web parts
- Everything builds and can be browsed as expected (no bugs/404's etc.)

Still no luck. Is there something else I'm missing? Or any similar scenarios you've came across?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about your search crawl rules?

Does the full crawl log say that it's excluded or does the log say that it indexed it but it doesn't show up in search results?

Comment: It doesn't appear in any of the logs as far as I can see. To check crawl rules I'm not sure - but this is crawling other sites no probs. Thanks a lot for your reply Steve.

Comment: Well, if it's not listed at all in your crawl log, then that isn't good.  That means that it's not even trying to crawl the site.  Check your content source settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of users in the site (usually over ~1800), your site will no longer be crawled. This count includes unique users in sharepoint groups or site permissions. Users in active directory security groups don't count towards the limit (the security group counts as 1).

If this were the case, you would likely be receiving a message like `The parameter is incorrect` in your crawl log.

A very good explanation of the issue here: [SharePoint Indexing Limited by 64 kB ACL Limit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattlind/archive/2007/11/02/sharepoint-indexing-limited-by-64-kb-acl-limit.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The most ubiquitous reason that Sharepoint Search/Crawling fails completely is the legendary [Loopback Security Check](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons that I'm thinking of

- the targeted site is not part of any **content source**
- the **crawler account** that is used has no access to the target site
- A specific **robots.txt** is available at the root of the web application preventing a proper crawl / indexing
- A too generic **crawl rule** is defined or wrongly positioned (cascading effect)
- an unconfigured **binding / AAM** is used to access the site.

The easiest way to understand what's going wrong, if the suggestions above do not help is to install Fiddler on the Crawl server and set the Search Service Application proxy to the one used by Fiddler. That way whenever you start a full / incremental crawl, you'll have a clear view of what's preventing / blocking the crawl.

Hope it helped !